# "So that it be" vs "so that it is"

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood

Recently on IRC I said this:

> I do not believe in proving the correctness of already constructed programs. I believe in formally deriving programs so that they be correct.

And I got almost instantly corrected:

> DijkstraGroupie: So that they *are* correct, you mean.

Checking on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive), I found the following:

> *I want you to give this money to him so that he **have** enough for lunch.* (the conjunction "so that" takes a subjunctive in formal English)

What usage is correct, in this case?

Comment: Subjunctive mood is normally used in phrases such as "I demand he be in time, tomorrow," or "if she were rich, she would live on Long Island." I don't see any rule about using the subjective with _so that_.

Comment: Without wishing to get bogged down in the question of whether OP's **"be"** here is "subjunctive" or not (or indeed whether the subjunctive even exists in modern English), I would say there's nothing wrong with it apart from sounding a little dated/stilted/formal. The Wikipedia example, on the other hand, seems hopelessly archaic, and I wouldn't put any faith in *(the conjunction "so that" takes a subjunctive in formal English)*.

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing wrong with: *I believe in formally deriving programs so that they be correct.* The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (p1000) lists *so (that)* as one of the two purposive prepositions (along with *in order that*) that can take the subjunctive, although this is not common. The example given is:

- Extraordinary precautions were taken so that no stranger be allowed in the city.

Comment: I have only the stripped-down version of the CGEL, where the authors say that instead of ‘It is essential that he keep us informed', ‘many speakers would here use a present tense in preference to the slightly more formal subjunctive’. That certaihly seems to be the case in BrEng.

Comment: @Barrie England, As a British native speaker of English I would use the subjunctive in such constructions on only the rarest of occasions and after much consideration as to whether the context would justify it. I never use it in unplanned speech or writing.

Comment: CGEL's example sounds very dated, but OP's violates Orwell's Sixth Law.

Answer (score 5):

The subjunctive is rare in British English, but perhaps less so in American English. In either variety, *I want you to give this money to him so that he have enough for lunch* seems a most peculiar sentence. In British English it would be expressed as *I want you to give this money to him so that he's got enough for lunch*. In British English, too, your example *so that they be correct* would sound extremely formal. *So that they're correct* is what you'd hear most of the time.

Comment: Is it uncommon in British English to say sentences like: "It is important that he attend the meeting"? I know it's OK in American English. If it's not in BrE, what's the correct/common equivalent?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: It's not unheard of, but BrEng tends either to use the indicative in such cases ('important that he attends') or the modal verb 'should' followed by the plain form of the main verb ('important that he should attend').

Comment: The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (p994) has an almost identical example: It lists each of the following as correct: *It is essential that everyone attend the meeting. / It is essential that everyone attends the meeting. / It is essential that everyone should attend the meeting.*

Comment: @Shoe: Does it use the word 'correct'?

Comment: Shouldn't it be *"..give this money to him so that he **has** enough for lunch"* (or *"..so that **he'll have** enough for lunch"*)?

Comment: @Barrie, The examples I cited follow the CGEL's general introduction to the 3 main uses of the subjunctive. The text introducing the examples reads: "*In none of the above three cases is the subjunctive construction obligatory. Two other possibilities have to be considered, as in the [b/c] examples in:*", and then it lists the examples I cite above. So, *correct* is my own extrapolation.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft: Yes, both of those are also possible (but I wouldn't say that's what they SHOULD be).

Comment: @Shoe: Thank you. I have said elsewhere that I find the words 'correct' and 'incorrect' inadequate in describing language and I would been surprised to find Huddleston and Pullum using them. Hence my question.

Comment: @Barrie England, I agree that terms such as correct/incorrect can be problematic. In fact, I wrote a [page](http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/easy/wrong.htm) about it for my website, that might interest you.

Comment: @Shoe: Yes, TEFL is one of the few places where it is helpful, because NNS prdouce constructions that no NS would.

Answer (score 5):

While using subjuntive, the part you should be careful is not "that" or "so that". It is used after certain expressions. Pay attention:

1) **the verbs**

ask, command, demand, insist, propose, recommend, request, suggest + (that) + subjuntive

> He insists that the car park be locked at night.

2) **expressions such as**

it is desirable, essential, important, necessary, vital + (that) + subjuntive

> It is essential that she be present.

Answer (score 4):

You really can't trust Wikipedia about matters of "grammatical correctness". I'm afraid that's quite wrong. There is no "subjunctive" to "take" in English, and in any case *so that* does not govern an untensed *that*-clause the way, say, *important* does.

- *It's **important** that they **be** on time tomorrow.*

Untensed *that*-clauses (which are often called "subjunctive") are just one more variety of complement, like infinitives without *to* or embedded questions, and in Modern English these are governed by predicates, not conjunctions.

Patrick Henry famously said "If this be treason, make the most of it." That was over 200 years ago. However, nobody talks (or writes) that way any more.

Comment: Could you perhaps include a good source which would back up your claim that this is *not* subjunctive, but rather an "untensed that clause". I googled the latter term and didn't find anything useful. [One of the sources] (http://ebooks.unibuc.ro/filologie/cornilescu/3.pdf) implied that the term refers to examples like " For it to seem that John was late would be an erro"

Comment: Far be it from me to argue, but who said there is no subjunctive in English?

Comment: +1, but I'm a bit unsure of your claim that "in Modern English these [untensed *that*-clauses] are governed by predicates, not conjunctions." It seems like that would rule out not only \*"so that they be on time" (which I think is wrong) but also "in order that they be on time" (which I think is right, at least in American English). (Also, I think you mean Present-Day English specifically, and not Modern English in general; otherwise your Patrick Henry example would defeat your point.)

Comment: "[Subjunctive](http://www.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsSubjunctiveMood.htm)" is a term from Latin that refers to an inflection class (a "[mood](http://www.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsMoodAndModality.htm)") for verbs. Every Latin verb had several special subjunctive forms -- distinguishable instantly from all other forms of that verb -- which were used in certain constructions. English does not have any moods; English verbs (not counting _be_) have at most 6 forms, none of which are inflected for mood of any sort.

Comment: There are a number of constructions in English that are used in certain ways reminiscent of the Latin (or even more of the German) subjunctive moods, but there is no consistent or useful definition of what is "subjunctive" and what is not in English, though there is great faith in its existence. I believe that the reason for this may be that identifying a sentence as "subjunctive" makes people feel good, rather like identifying the "parts of speech", even though it contributes nothing to understanding the sentence or its grammar.

Comment: By the way, I think you're right, ruakh, in suggesting that "in order that" can be an untensed clause, too. I hadn't thought of that one.

Comment: The subjunctive in Latin is not always distinguishable from indicative forms: it depends on the form. // Why do you say that there is no consistent definition of the (present) subjunctive in English? Any instance of *be* used where one would expect a finite verb is called a subjunctive. It seems very straightforward. I know the CGEL is very syncretic (it wants to throw all *be*'s on a heap). That's fine, but it is just one approach.

Comment: There is no consistent definition of "subjunctive" in English. What's called "subjunctive" includes some (but not all) uses of _be_, some but not all uses of modal auxiliaries, some but not all uses of past tense, some but not all complements, and a lot of idioms. Descriptions purporting to be such definitions always sat that so-and-so ***may*** appear, never that it ***always*** appears. Finally, descriptions of "subjuncive" always confuse grammar with meaning and intention, which is my main reason for not using the term. It adds nothing and only confuses.

Comment: Providentially, Geoff Pullum [posted today on Language Log](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3809) about the sogenannte "Subjunctive" in English.

Answer (score 2):

I'm an hispanophone, francophone and anglophone.

Let me tell you how I understand the use of subjunctives.

> "It is important to be on time"

This sentence is understood as an order (something believed with certainty) and the feeling is cold and generalist or apathetic.

> "It is important that **you** be on time"

This sentence is understood as an advice (something subjective) and the feeling is warm and empathetic.

It is very important that we stop simplifying the language. Simplicity as sending a message without all the necessary data that others would need to decode the feelings in our words. Unless, we're talking on behalf of a higher entity like an organization or a political party.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I'm afraid I take the exact opposite interpretation of your example sentences. The first sets out a general rule. The second singles out an individual, and can be interpreted as accusatory. In any case, however, this does not seem to answer the question at hand, and as this is a Q&A site rather than a discussion forum, it may be converted to a comment or deleted. I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of how StackExchange operates, and hope you continue to participate.

Comment: Well It does answer the question. The explicit answer is that there is no correct answer, using subjonctive is a matter of personal style and self expression. But, If a sentence is formulated with a subjective meaning then the subjonctive most be applied because It is the grammatical rule and also coherence. Otherwise, If a sentence implies certainty or accusation then there is obviously no reason for using the subjonctive form.