# Why we don't add "s" to the verb in this sentence?

Tags: verb-agreement

I came across this question in one of the English standardize tests in my country:

It is required that the new student _____ in an extra English conversation course.

1. enroll
2. enrolled
3. will enroll
4. would enroll
5. is enrolling

The suggested key states that the answer is **1. enroll**
From my understanding, that choice is correct because we supposed to use present simple tense when stating such factual information. However, why wouldn't it be **enrolls** since the subject of the verb is **new student** which is a singular noun? Or that choice is correct because of any other reason or grammar rules?

Comment: [This article](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/subjunctive_mood.htm) might help: "The subjunctive mood is the verb form used to explore a hypothetical situation (e.g., If I were you) or to express a wish, a demand, or a suggestion (e.g., I demand he *be* present)."

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["So that it be" vs "so that it is".](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58634/so-that-it-be-vs-so-that-it-is) It's not to do with ***singular*** or ***plural*** verb form - it's *"**tensed**"* or ***infinitive***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is American English so wedded to the subjunctive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76578/why-is-american-english-so-wedded-to-the-subjunctive) [_She suggested that he go to the cinema_ vs the indicative _She suggested that he goes to the cinema_]

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the verb follows the expression of a wish, a desire, a command, a requirement, and is therefore expressed in the subjunctive mood. The subjunctive usage demands that the verb appear in its basic form *enroll* rather than *enrolls*. Note how I have similarly used the subjunctive form of *appear* in my previous sentence because it follows *demands that*.

You may find a good account of the construction and of the verbs that lead to subjunctive use in

> [Learn Grammar](https://www.learngrammar.net/english-grammar/subjunctive)
>
> The Subjunctive in English is the mood of a verb that always comes in the simple/base form. The subjunctive mood of verbs comes after some certain verbs indicating that one person wants/insists/desires another person to do something. Those certain verbs are called subjunctive verbs.

The link also provides a useful list of relevant verbs such as require, urge, suggest and several others.